# Probability of terms involving dependent random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

I want to calculate the probability as
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A} = \mathbb{P}\left(B X > \zeta_s, CXY > \zeta_s\right),
\end{equation}
where B, C, and $\zeta_s$ are positive constants, while X and Y are independent exponential random variables with means $\lambda_x$ and $\lambda_y$, respectively. In above equation, $X$ makes two terms inside the probability dependent.

To express above equation as the product of independent random variables, we condition the term $\mathbb{P}\left(B X > \zeta_s, CXY > \zeta_s\right)$ on $X$. 
Thus,
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}\left(B X > \zeta_s, CXY > \zeta_s|X= x\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(B X > \zeta_s|X=x\right)\mathbb{P}\left(CXY > \zeta_s|X=x\right).
\end{equation}
To get the final answer, we then average the expression obtained by solving above equation over $X$.

But, for a fixed $X = x$, the first term on the right hand side of the above equation becomes $\mathbb{P}\left(B x > \zeta_s\right)$, which is the probability of a constant greater than a constant.

I do not know how to proceed with this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Conditioning a continuous random variable on a single value is problematic (you are effectively dividing by zero).

You need to consider the joint distribution $P_{X,Y}$ which can be expressed by a density function on $\mathbb R^+\times\mathbb R^+$ by taking the product of the individual densities of $X$ and $Y$ (since they are independent).

Now integrate this joint density over the area that is delimited by the conditions $Bx>\zeta$ and $Cxy>\zeta.$

$$P=\int_{x=\zeta/B}^\infty\int_{y=\zeta/(Cx)}^\infty\rho_x(x)\rho_y(y)dx\ dy.$$